# Problema de Cotejamiento en BD y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Cuando ejecuto la sentencia UPDATE en PHP, para que se guarden los cambios en la base de datos (PHPMyAdmin), la información se almacena con caracteres raros, es decir, no se reconoce la letra ñ ni los acentos....

La ñ aparece así: aÃ±os
Los acentos aparecen así: regiÃ³n:

Debo agregar alguna sentencia y/o prefijo al escribir UPDATE nombreTabla SET....  ¿Por qué pasa eso? 
En mi conexión a BD, tengo esto:

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$bd_config['basedatos'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['pass'], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES  \'UTF8\''));
```

Y ni así, se respeta......

Cabe mencionar que el cotejamiento, tanto para mis tablas, como para la base de datos en general es UTF8_UNICODE_CI

Comment: Puedes poner el código php que lanza la consult

Comment: Con que editor de texto estas trabajando? asegurate de que el editor tambien este bien configurado

Comment: Claro, mira este es el código: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$titulo = limpiardattos($_POST['titulo']);
$descripcion = limpiardattos($_POST['texto']);
$id = limpiardattos($_POST['id']);

$statement = $conexion->prepare(
'UPDATE informacion_empresa SET title = :titulo, 
descripcion = :texto WHERE id = :id'
 ); 

$statement->execute(array(
  ':titulo' => $titulo,
  ':texto' => $descripcion,
  ':id' => $id
 ));

header('Location: ' . RUTA . '/admin/editar.php');

}

Comment: Estoy trabajando con Sublime Text 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes que asegurarte la codificación del lado del cliente y del PHP
yo uso el siguiente codigo

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
if (function_exists("iconv") && PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600)
    {
    iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
    iconv_set_encoding("input_encoding", "UTF-8");
    iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "UTF-8");
    }
elseif (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600)
    {
    ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
    }
```